# How to make foldl consume constant memory?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, fold

We define the following data type `Stupid`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.List (foldl')
data Stupid = Stupid {content::V.Vector Int, ul::Int} deriving Show
```

Now I have two slightly different code.

```
foldl' (\acc x->Stupid{content=(content acc) V.// [(x,x+123)],ul=1}) (Stupid {content=V.replicate 10000 10,ul=1}) $ take 100000 $ cycle [0..9999]
```

takes constant memory (~100M), while

```
foldl' (\acc x->Stupid{content=(content acc) V.// [(x,x+123)],ul=ul acc}) (Stupid {content=V.replicate 10000 10,ul=1}) $ take 100000 $ cycle [0..9999]
```

takes a huge amount of memory(~8G).

Theoretically, only one copy of the current `Stupid` object is needed though out the process for both cases. I don't understand why there is such a difference in memory consumption if I want to access and record the `ul acc`.

Can someone explain why this happens and give a workaround for constant memory if I need to access `ul acc`? Thanks.

Note: I know that I can do replacements of a vector in batch, this script is just for demonstration purpose, so please don't modify that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to force the fields of `Stupid` and see if that helps.

```
let f acc x = c `seq` a `seq` Stupid{content=c,ul=a}
       where
       c = content acc V.// [(x,x+123)]
       a = ul acc
in foldl' f (Stupid {content=V.replicate 10000 10,ul=1}) $
   take 100000 $
   cycle [0..9999]
```

This should be nearly equivalent to forcing the parameters of the function:

```
foldl' (\acc x -> acc `seq` x `seq` 
        Stupid{content=(content acc) V.// [(x,x+123)],ul=ul acc})
   (Stupid {content=V.replicate 10000 10,ul=1}) $ take 100000 $ cycle [0..9999]
```

(This can also be written with bang patterns, if one prefers those.)

Another option, more aggressive, would be to use strictness annotations in the definition of the `Stupid` constructor.

```
data ... = Stupid { content = ! someType , ul :: ! someOtherType }
```

This will always force those fields in the whole program.

Comment: Thanks! The first code snippet consumes constant memory while the second does not.